# Pipewire-pulse: No sound, "playback open failed: Device or resource busy"

Tags: pulseaudio, pipewire

I'm running `wireplumber` + `pipewire` + `pipewire-pulse` and I can't get any sound out of the HDMI cable.  `pactl list sinks` shows all my audio devices as `SUSPENDED` and `journalctl --user -u pipewire` shows a wall of error messages for every device like this

```
spa.audioadapter: params Spa:Enum:ParamId:EnumFormat: 0:0 (follower format) Device or resource busy
spa.alsa: '_ucm0001.hw:Audio,3': playback open failed: Device or resource busy
```

What I think is the problem is something else has a lock on my devices in `/dev/snd`

```
# fuser -fv /dev/snd/*
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  cheez      1383 F.... pipewire
                     cheez      1388 F.... wireplumber
                     root       3710 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  cheez      1388 F.... wireplumber
                     root       3710 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p:   root       3710 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D1c:   root       3710 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D1p:   root       3710 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D2c:   root       3710 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D3p:   root       3710 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC1D9p:   root       3710 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/seq:        cheez      1383 F.... pipewire
```

I don't have `pulseaudio` installed.  I have `pipewire-pulse` instead. Why does root have a lock on my sound cards?  How can I unlock

Comment: `homeassistant-supervised` was the culprit locking my sound cards. As soon as I uninstalled it I had sound again.  No restarting anything required.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @cheezsteak for the pointer. For anyone else running into the same issue, it has been suggested on Home Assistant's repository to prevent the container from taking control of the host's sound card.

> Just create a file /etc/udev/rules.d/89-pulseaudio.rules with the following content:
>
> `DRIVERS=="bcm2835_audio", ENV{PULSE_IGNORE}="1"`
>
> If needed, replace "bcm2835_audio" with the driver of your card, you
> can find it with
>
> `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/snd/controlC0)`

[Source](https://github.com/home-assistant/plugin-audio/issues/12#issuecomment-1179508339)